# ImportError: No module named <module name>

Tags: python, module, package

I know this question has been asked numerous time but still then i am not able to figure out whats is going wrong in my case.

This is my package structure.

```
sound/                          
      __init__.py               
      formats/                  
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
              aiffread.py
              aiffwrite.py
              auread.py
              auwrite.py

      effects/                  
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
              reverse.py

      filters/                  
              __init__.py
              equalizer.py
              vocoder.py
              karaoke.py
      testsound.py
```

When i Run:

```
python testsound.py
```

It fails:

```
    from sound.formats.wavread import *
ImportError: No module named sound.formats.wavread
```

$ cat testsound.py

```
from filters import karaoke

def main():
    karaoke.run()
```

$ cat karaoke.py

```
from sound.formats.wavread import *  # ---> Fails Here 
from sound.formats import wavwrite

def run():
    readmusic()    # This function is present in wavread
    wavwrite.writeMusic()
```

Comment: Have you set PYTHONPATH? You can import modules relative to where you ran the script from `from formats.wavread import *` should work when running `testsound`

Comment: `testsound` is a script file *inside* the package directory. You can't then expect the `sound` package to have been added to your Python path. Either explicitly add the parent directory of `sound` to `sys.path`, move `testsound.py` out of `sound`, or use `python -m sound.testsound` (with the current working directory in the directory containing `sound`)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Can you please let me know how to do it.

Comment: @IainShelvington , I have explicitly added "/Users/may/Documents/MAY/Projects/MyPrograms/Python/sound" to my PYTHONPATH

Comment: See the duplicates, where I already explain how to do this.